# converting blob to varchar returns null in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, blob

I have a field in my database table with data type as `MEDIUMBLOB`.
How can I get the content as text/string using a `SELECT` query in SQL.
the content's `MIMETYPE` is `Binary/Image`.

Actually I am uploading txt file and inserting into the table.

There is no problem when i upload `english` text file.But When i upload `malayalam` text file, it returns null value.

I tried with this

```
SELECT CONVERT(uploaded_file USING utf8) AS content FROM table_name

SELECT CAST(uploaded_file AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) AS content FROM table_name
```

I am getting `null` value

how to get `malayalam` text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Cannot reproduce this. Can you check if column contains any not-null data?

Comment: Column contains data and i am able to save file also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written some code here - http://rextester.com/CHYY75133

Take a look, it creates, populates and reads the table. The result is predictable - we have some bytes, and get the word 'രാകേഷ്' (utf8 encoding is used).

```
-- Script was generated by Devart dbForge Studio for MySQL, Version 7.2.58.0
SET NAMES 'utf8';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table1;
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  st VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  bl MEDIUMBLOB DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES
(1, 'hello', x'E0B4B0E0B4BEE0B495E0B587E0B4B7E0B58D'); -- രാകേഷ്

SELECT bl, CAST(bl AS CHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8) FROM table1;
```